# class() vs. type() in Ruby

Tags: ruby, syntax

What's the difference between the class and type methods in Ruby? I've noticed that type works to find the type of some classes but not others.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The key difference is that `Object#type` is deprecated.  From the RDoc for Object#type:

> Deprecated synonym for Object#class.

Here's why you should use `Object#class`:

> Returns the class of obj, now
>   preferred over Object#type, as an
>   object‘s type in Ruby is only loosely
>   tied to that object‘s class. This
>   method must always be called with an
>   explicit receiver, as class is also a
>   reserved word in Ruby.

In reality, you probably want to use `Object#respond_to?` instead of checking for the class of an object in most cases.

Comment: If it's a synonym, why would I get an undefined method error when I call type on a class I've defined myself? But the same thing does not happen when I call the class method for the same class. undefined method error doesn't sound like what you would get for a deprecated method.

Comment: @Chris Collins my guess is that the doc is off, and that it's not a strict synonym.  Point remains that Object#type is a no-use method.

Comment: @Chris Collins to expand on @kch's comment, most of the time you want to know "Is this object capable of printing its name?" or something.  So using o.class == Person is a blunt instrument in this case.  Better to do o.respond_to?(:display_name), which will work on a Person, or a Dog, or a Company.  Google Ruby Duck Typing for more.

Answer (score 15):

`#type` is a synonym for `#class`, but it's deprecated in ruby 1.8, and apparently gone from ruby 1.9. Just use `#class` everywhere.

```
# For ruby 1.8

$ ri Object#type
------------------------------------------------------------ Object#type
     obj.type   => class
------------------------------------------------------------------------
     Deprecated synonym for Object#class.


# For ruby 1.9

$ ri1.9 Object#type
Nothing known about Object#type
```

Comment: If it's a synonym, why would I get an undefined method error when I call type on a class I've defined myself? But the same thing does not happen when I call the class method for the same class. undefined method error doesn't sound like what you would get for a deprecated method.

Comment: Are you on ruby 1.9? On ruby 1.8 I don't get an error, just a warning about the deprecation.

Comment: And if you're on ruby 1.9, well, deprecation means it'll be removed some when, and looks like 1.9 is that when.